# How do I search unread messages in outlook.com (Office 365)

Tags: outlook.com

How do I filter search results to only include unread messages in Office 365 outlook.com? I've tried `read:no`, but that looks for messages containing *read* and *no*.

[image: Office 365 Outlook Search]

Answer (score 22):

I was also struggling to get all the unread emails (including from the subfolders) in Outlook Office 365. The closest I could find was the following search query:

```
isread:no
```

[image: Search Email]

In case of Desktop client, this can be achieved with the Search Folders.

```
Search Folders -> Right Click -> New Search Folders -> Unread Mail
```

But, unfortunately this feature is not available yet for the Office 365. Here is the uservoice link for this search folders:

[UserVoice - Outlook Office 365 Search Folders](https://outlook.uservoice.com/forums/313228--outlook-on-the-web-office-365/suggestions/9624684-search-folders)

Comment: `isread:no` search is available in web outlook, "unread search folder" is not

Comment: Not a good sign, that link is broken and MS is moving away from UserVoice. Now just 'submit your feedback' to a blackhole help icon. https://www.windowscentral.com/microsoft-confirms-its-moving-uservoice-office-365-and-more

Answer (score 3):

At the top of the interface for a folder (e.g., Inbox), next to the folder name, there's a pull menu called `Filter`. Pull that down and select `Unread`.

Answer (score 2):

There is an easy way to solve this issue. I created an unread mail folder in the NEW desktop version and added it to favorites; it automatically synced to outlook.com (This is a business/paid account). This function may not work under free Outlook accounts.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look on the screenshot below where "filter" is circled on the right. We have to simply filter with "Unread".

[image]

Comment: This query is for unread accross all folders, not folder specific.

Answer (score 0):

While you can filter for Unread messages in any folder, that `search` does not seem to include subfolders at all. Since the SearchFolders feature isn't yet available in the Outlook Web App, there is no way to store the filter/search you have to now manually perform everytime.